# Lock object dictionary which frees unneeded items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, garbage-collection

I need to synchronize a critical section, but only if the code is working with the same data (determined by IDs of objects). That's why I implemented a lock object container which dynamically creates lock objects based on a string identifier. Lock objects are stored in a dictionary and reused if somebody asks for an object with the same key.

The problem is that there are millions of combinations of the locking key and lock objects currently stay in the dictionary and consume memory forever.

How to design such dictionary, so that it removes unneeded lock objects and thus frees memory?

My ideas:

1. Store lock objects as weak references and traverse the dictionary once upon a time and remove keys where value !IsAlive
2. Store lock objects as weak references, but this time implement a Finalizer in the LockObject class and remove the key from the dictionary when it fires

Do I have any other options?

Comment: A small explanation about your real problem you want to solve would be good.

Comment: The critical section I am talking about is calculating whether a user fulfills certain condition or not. Condition is specified by the admin of the website (can be very complex). Condition evaluation can be fired by various events and has to be synchronized, but only for individual UserID and ConditionID combination. Did that help?

Comment: I used `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` a lot, in similar cases

Comment: Well, as far as I know, MemoryCache can free item even if there is a reference to it somewhere else. This disqualifies it, because I do not want the object to be freed when some thread is using it to lock. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is very old, but in case someone stumbles upon this and has the same issue, take a look at [AsyncKeyedLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncKeyedLock) which solves the problem. You can use:

```
using (await _locker.LockAsync(myObject.Id))
{
   ...
}
```